# fileExistsAtPath returns NO for a directory that exists

Tags: objective-c, ios

`fileExistsAtPath` is returning NO for a directory that exists. If I have the following code:

```
NSURL *newDirectoryPath = ... // path does not begin with a tilda
                              // and is created using URLByAppendingPathComponent:isDirectory:

BOOL directoryExists = [self.fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[newDirectoryPath absoluteString]];
if (NO == directoryExists)
{
    BOOL ret = [self.fileManager moveItemAtURL:self.currentPresentationDirectoryPath toURL:newDirectoryPath error: &err];
    // ret is YES, err is nil

    directoryExists = [self.fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[newDirectoryPath absoluteString]];
}
```

Even though the directory has just been created successfully with `moveItemAtURL`, `fileExistsAtPath` is still returning NO.

I know the documentation says this:

> Attempting to predicate behavior based on the current state of the
>   file system or a particular file on the file system is not
>   recommended. Doing so can cause odd behavior in the case of file
>   system race conditions.

But I want to understand what the issue is here -  if I close the app and relaunch it then the first check for `fileExistsAtPath` in the code above is still returning NO, even though the directory was previously successfully created during the prior execution of the code, and I can see the directory in the Organizer, and I can also successfully read from the contents of the directory etc. etc.

P.S. is there no `fileExistsAtURL`: method?

Comment: NSLog the path you're using and make sure it's what you think it is.

Comment: Can't test on this machine, but isn't that supposed to be [newDirectoryPath path] instead of [newDirectoryPath absoluteString]?

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson - that was it -thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you have an `NSURL`, `-absoluteURL` won't return a usable path for `NSFileManager`. It will return the absolute URL with the `file://` prefix. E.g.: `file:///path/to/file`.

Instead try to use an other method, like `-path`. Check if that works.

```
NSURL *myURL = /* some url */;
NSString *myPath;
BOOL exi;

myPath = [myURL path];
exi = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPath];
if(!exi) {
    NSLog(@"File does not exist");
}
```